# TaskRouter in twilio-php library for Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, twilio-php

I am using Symfony3 for building a Twilio TaskRouter based application which is using the twilio-php library.

All the other components in Symfony use the PS-0 or PS-4 naming convention while the standard twilio-php library does not use the same, thus I am not directly able to use certain classes(in my case taskrouter) .

The class in question is `Services_Twilio_TaskRouter_Worker_Capability` which resides in `twilio-php/sdk/Services/CapabilityTaskRouter.php`.

Symfony expects the class to be in the directory `vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio/TaskRouter/Worker/Capability` directory, which it fails to find.

Is there a way to include `vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/CapabilityTaskRouter.php`
in a symfony class and extend the `Services_Twilio_TaskRouter_Worker_Capability` class?

Comment: Have you tried installing https://github.com/fridolin-koch/VreshTwilioBundle which wraps the Twilio SDK and lets you call it as a service?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the lib in the vendor by running:

```
composer require twilio/sdk
```

and composer will add the lib to the vendor folder 
and in you controller you will be able to call it like :

```
$sid = "ACXXXXXX"; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/user/account
$token = "YYYYYY"; // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/user/account

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
  '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
  '8881231234', // Text this number
  "Hello monkey!"
);

print_r($message->sid);
```

Comment: Yes, the above is exactly what i did. The above works when i am using the standard php framework but as soon as i start using symfony this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is possible. To keep the include logic separated from your project code, you should create a wrapper class that follows PSR-4 naming conventions, that simply extends the Twilio class.

```
<?php

    namespace MyProject\Service;

    require_once('path/to/twilio-php/sdk/Services/CapabilityTaskRouter.php');

    class CapabilityTaskRouter extends \Services_Twilio_TaskRouter_Worker_Capability
    {
    }
```

This is the way, we did a lot of times to integrate libraries not following PSR auloading concepts into our projects.

Comment: I tried to add the require_once function but the same keeps erroring out saying that it is not able to find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio employee here.

I went down the route of implementing a helper extension to https://github.com/fridolin-koch/VreshTwilioBundle and in that process discovered this was really a twilio-php helper library problem due to the naming conventions and the autoloading of these particular classes.

I intend to finish up the helper extension to VreshTwilioBundle, however, this is the PR that I have submitted that should keep you moving forward:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/pull/288